# When drilling your wire ways in the walls, what is the standard height in the horizontal height from the floor?

Tags: electrical

When drilling your wire ways in the walls, what is the standard height in the horizontal height from the floor?

Comment: There may be some local conventions, but in my locale, there are not any, and wires could be and are run at any level.

Answer (score 3):

There are no standard heights. We usually run them close to the height that the receptacles are to save wire many of the homes I have wired run from 8” to 24” with most 12-16” I like the taller ones because boring the holes through the studs is easier a little higher, just make you bore your hole in the center of the board so there is 1-1/4” or more to the edge or you will have to add nail plates.

Comment: Good mention of the hole in the center of the board..... +

Answer (score 1):

Most outlets are 16 to 18" above the floor and I usually run, drill, my cable about 6" above the top of the boxes. I know of no standard height on doing this. you could go below the outlets but that tough on the knees.

Comment: outlet height, plus the (6") radius of your pipe bender, *plus one*, +1. Whoops? *People also bought* a tight radius pipe bender. Otherwise, they go where, me, holding a right angle drill horizontally, contacts the stud; ~40", unless there's a switch, then it's 48+6 (+ at least 1 for error; usually eyeball ~3). Bending is for the new guy.

Answer (score 0):

NEC codes requires running outlets from 15-48 inches from the floor if they are less than 30A. Most contractors will run them at 17-20 to ensure they are consistent, but also still above 15 inches when additional flooring is added.

Comment: This is good info. If you would [edit] in the specific NEC reference, it would be _great_ info.

Comment: Not good info.  This is Google copypasta and is not accurate.

Comment: There is no hard requirement in the NEC they can be in the floor! Or in the baseboard, there are no maximums except out doors and if you do not want to not have tamper proof put above 5.5’ you may be thinking of ADA requirements in commercial facilities but not the National Electric Code (NFPA70)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the stature of the electrician. Holes are bored horizontally through the wall studs at whatever height is comfortable to hold the drill! That seems to be a little below waist-high.

Outlet boxes are installed at a height equal to the length of the handle of my hammer. I stand the hammer on its head next to the stud, align the junction box, then lift the hammer and use it to drive the nails that hold the junction box to the stud. There's nothing special about the height of the hammer; using it as my guide saves me having to change tools (set the hammer down, pick up the measuring tape, extend it, then set that down and pick up the hammer).

Comment: I marked "box center line" on all the studs where boxes would go, put the tape back in the tool belt, then went around and attached the boxen. I suppose this would have worked, too.